# python - unpacking byte strings into very large arbitrary-size ints

Tags: python

I am trying to unpack a byte array of arbitrary int-size n into a python list/array.
For example, the byte array may contain a list of 256-bit values, or it may contain normal 32-bit values, or 4-bit values, or 1-bit values, etc. I am looking for a function that would do the following:

```py
>>> unpack_values(32, b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
[4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295]
>>> unpack_values(128, b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
[340282366920938463463374607431768211455]
>>> unpack_values(1, b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function would have to know about the endianness of the bitstream. For example, does `0b1000000000000000` represent 1, 32768 or something else?

If you are willing to stick to multiples of 8 bits, you could do it like this:

```
In [1]: val = b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'                        
Out[1]: b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'

In [2]: product = 1                                                                                      
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: for b in val: 
   ...:     product *= b 
   ...:                                                                                                  

In [4]: product                                                                                          
Out[4]: 319626579315078487616775634918212890625
```

If you want to use fractional bytes, have a look at the [bitstring](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring) module.